# Update column inside join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am facing 1 problem and need help.

I have 2 tables - MainTable and DWTable.

```
MainTable - (ItemName varchar(255) NULL (unique), ItemCode varchar(255) NULL),
DWTable - (ItemName varchar(255) NULL, ItemCode varchar(255) NULL).
```

Common column - ItemName varchar(255) NULL.

ItemName is unique in MainTable but multiple in DWTable.

Now, I need to update MainTable.ItemCode from DWTable.ItemCode.
As MainTable has only 1 record which can be joined with multiple columns of DWTable.We have many options available for MainTable.ItemCode

DWTable.ItemCode can have 3 types of values -

- A. `not like '%Red%' and not like '%Yellow%'` -- priority 1
- B. `like '%Red%'` -- priority 2
- C. `Like '%yellow%'` ---priority 3

If A do not exists, value should be B else C.

Please help.

```
update MainTable 
set ItemCode = DWTable.ItemCode 
from Maintable inner join DWTable on MainTable.ItemName = DWTable.ItemName
```

For 1 particular ItemName 'RREE', DWTable has 6 records.
so MainTable.ItemCode will be updated by 6th row value of DWTable.
For 1 Itemname 'RREERR', we have around 80 records

Comment: Show us some sample data and expected result.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Could you provide the query or queries that you have tried?

Comment: Hi Jaun, Steven.                                                                                             update MainTable
set ItemCode = DWTable.ItemCode
from Maintable inner join DWTable
on MainTable.ItemCode = DWTable.ItemCode.

For 1 particular ItemCode 'RREE', DWTable has 6 records.
so MainTable.ItemCode will be updated by 6th row value of DWTable.For 1 ItemCode 'RREERR', we have around 80 records.

Answer (score 1):

```
update MainTable
set ItemCode = (
    select top 1 dw.ItemCode
    from DWTable dw
    where dw.ItemName = MainTable.ItemName /* same full name here for correlation */
    order by
        case
            when dw.ItemCode not like '%Red%' and dw.ItemCode not like '%Yellow%' then 1
            when dw.ItemCode like '%Red%' then 2
            when dw.ItemCode like '%Yellow%' then 3
        end
)
```

My first thought is something like that although I usually avoid `top`. The bigger problem I see is that you clearly are going to have ties within the priority buckets.

For all practical purposes I've duplicated JaimeD77's answer which hadn't appeared when I posted mine. You can see the variation on the theme of ordering by priority and taking the first one. Using the `from` clause in `update` can introduce some problems so there are reasons to favor the subquery approach.

Comment: Thanks Shawnt00 for the solution !!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do what you want using a CTE.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  ItemName,
            ItemCode,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ItemName ORDER BY 
                    (CASE WHEN ItemCode NOT LIKE '%Red%' AND ItemCode NOT LIKE '%Yellow%' THEN 1
                          WHEN ItemCode LIKE '%Red%' THEN 2
                          ELSE 3 END)) AS [ItemCodeOrder]

    FROM    DWTable
)
UPDATE  mt
SET     mt.ItemCode = cte.ItemCode
FROM    Maintable mt
        INNER JOIN cte ON mt.ItemName = cte.ItemName AND [ItemCodeOrder] = 1
```

The CTE will order the ItemCodes per ItemName from DWTable based on your priorities using ROW_NUMBER.  You might want to define how you want to handle the case where there are multiple values that meet the chosen priority.

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/631cf/1)